# press tab to go to selectbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a textbox follow by a selectbox, when i press "tab" on textbox, it doesnt go to selectbox. how to make it go to selectbox? is the solution required to use javascript? is there any workaround without using javascript?

editted:

```
<html>
<input type="text" tabindex="1" />
<select tabindex="2" >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</html>
```

i tried the selectbox on firefox, but fail. can it work on firefox? is it because of macos problem?  textbox seem ok .

Comment: i tested on opera,safari on macos, everything ok, except firefox. the selectbox seem cannot use tabindex. any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Use the html tabindex attribute:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/tabindex

The tabindex is used to define a sequence that users follow when they use the Tab key to navigate through a page. By default, the natural tabbing order will match the source order in the markup. In certain circumstances it may be necessary to override the default tabbing order...

A tabindex can start at 0 and increment in any value. As such, the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 would be fine, as would 10, 20, 30, 40, 50....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried tabindex?

```
<input type="text" tabindex=1 />
<select tabindex=2 >
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: With quotes around the numbers for XHTML ;)

Answer (score 1):

Setting a tabindex on both elements with a value of 1 higher for the selectbox than the one on  the textbox (1 and 2, 2 and 3, 99 and 100)